# How to fetch results from user,post,comments tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The title may not be the fit to the question perfectly ! pardon me

**Goal**

I want to achieve the `name` of the `user` who has done a `post`,the `description` of that post(`p_description`), the comments that are there on that `post`,and the name of those who has provided comments (`comment_description`)

How can I achieve that ?

I've three tables:

`user`

`post`   and

`comments`

**User** table is like :

`u_id` `name` and so...

**Post** table, here it is :

**u_id**   `p_id`  `p_description`

`u_id` as foreign key from `user` table ,

and the `Comments` table is:

`u_id`   `p_id` `comment_description`.

note that the **u_id** and **p_id** in table **comments** are both as foreign keys from table `user` and `post` respectively.

I'm writing the following query for the above **Goal**:

```
SELECT p_description,f_name,comment_description as COMMENT FROM user JOIN post ON user.u_id = post.u_id JOIN comments ON user.u_id = comments.u_id
```

It gives me the `post description`, `name of that guy who has done post`, and `the comments on that post`, and I want to have also the **name** of those guys who has done **comments** to that post.

If the problem is not explained well.

simply I want query for the above **GOAL** regarding those three tables.

Answer (score 0):

Join `user` once more on the user ID in `comments`.

```
SELECT u1.name,
       p1.p_description,
       u2.name,
       c1.comment_description
       FROM user u1
            INNER JOIN post p1
                       ON u1.u_id = p1.u_id
            INNER JOIN comments c1
                       ON c1.p_id = p1.p_id
            INNER JOIN user u2
                       ON u2.p_id = c1.p_id;
```

Comment: could you please explain how would I know that right now I need to use inner join , plus which thing would you like to recommend me to learn , so that next time I know where to use inner join , I mean, when do i need to use inner join? @sticky bit

Comment: also please explain a little about the last alias, and the first, just after select